# Prove $\{(x_1 ,x_2, 0) : x_1, x_2 ∈ F\}$ is a subspace of $F^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$(x_1 ,x_2, 0) + (y_1, y_2, 0) =((x_1 + y_1), (x_2 + y_2), 0)).$

So, it's closed under +.

$a(x_1 ,x_2, 0) = ax_1, ax_2, 0$.

So, it's closed under *.

Vector $(0, 0, 0) \in \mathbb F^3$ and its first two elements are in $ \mathbb F$, so $(0, 0, 0) \in \{(x_1 ,x_2, 0) : x_1, x_2 ∈ \mathbb F\}$.

Thus, $\{(x_1 ,x_2, 0) : x_1, x_2 ∈ \mathbb F\}$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb F^3$.

Please, check my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. This an alternative proof:

Let denote the given set by $S$. We have $S\ni(x_1,x_2,0)=x_1(1,0,0)+x_2(0,1,0)$ then we see that
$$S=\operatorname{span}((1,0,0),(0,1,0))$$
hence $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb F^3$.